# Google Maps API and Javascript and $(document).ready(function()

Tags: google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement google maps functionality and need to figure out where in my code the following script should be located:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-1"),myOptions); 

var myOptions2 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-2"),myOptions2);  

  var myOptions3 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    }
  map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas-3"),myOptions3);  

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng, 
  map: map, 
  title:"Map1" }); 

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng, 
  map: map2, 
  title:"Map2" }); 


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng, 
  map: map3, 
  title:"Map3" }); 

  map3.getStreetView().setPosition(myLatLng);
  map3.getStreetView().setVisible(true);
```

}

Currently, this code is inside the $(document{.ready(function(), and it seems to work fine, except that it causes the following jQuery/ajax functions to stop working:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: sURL + 'billingEventDetail/ajaxGetTaxClasses/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        taxClassData = data;
        jQuery.each(taxClassData.description , function(key, value){
            jQuery('#sel_tax_class').append(new Option(value, key));
        });
    }
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: sURL + 'billingEventDetail/ajaxGetBillingEventDetails/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        taxQualifierData = data;
        jQuery.each(taxQualifierData.description , function(key, value){
            jQuery('#sel_tax_qualifier').append(new Option(value, key));
        });
    }
});
```

When I temporarily disable the google maps code, the JQuery/Ajax starts working again.  Why am I having problems getting these two bits of code to work together?  Maybe the google maps code does not neet to be inside the $(document{.ready(function() ??

Does anyone have any ideas for me?

Comment: The google maps part need not to be inside $(document{.ready(function(), skip it for the rest of jquery also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to to put your google maps stuff int document.ready .  You're already registering an event listener on the window.load which calls initialize(), so that should be enough.  Move it all out of document.ready.  I can't guarantee that's what's causing the problems with your ajax though.